# is it possible in iOS get Game Center id or account?

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

I wan't use iOS GameCenter id to my own server id.
like google plus.

Is there any method to get game center id or account?

I have searched in internet this method. but it's return nil.

```
let player = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

player.playerID, player.displayName
```

playerID is nil and displayName is Me

I want uniqe key is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer() {

        var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

            if viewController != nil {

                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {

                if localPlayer.authenticated {

                    self.gameCenterEnabled = true
                    localPlayer.loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler({ (leaderboardIdentifier : String!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

                        if error != nil {
                            println(error.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            self.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier
                            ***above is your Game Center id***
                        }
                    })

                } else {
                    self.gameCenterEnabled = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In above code there self.leaderboardIdentifier is game centre id

Comment: at the line of " self.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier"

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: A leaderboardIdentifier is a string to identify a created Game Center leaderboard. It has nothing to do with any user id.